# Cannot get more than one result when using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core to query a list of objects that have a member dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, dynamic

I am using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core v1.0.8.18

**I am abbreviating the object I have--I have eliminated the JSON tags for serialization/deserialization as well as the constructor.** Below is the abbreviated class for a line item on an order. Please note that this object is deserialized from JSON, and the purpose of the "other" dictionary is to capture any name/value pair that is not explicitly defined in the object (which works exactly as it should in testing and production):

```
public partial class OrderRequestItem
{

    public string line_number { get; set; }
    public decimal quantity { get; set; }
    public string supplier_id { get; set; }
    public string supplier_aux_id { get; set; }
    public decimal unitprice { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string uom { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, object> other;

    public decimal extension
    {
        get
        {
            return unitprice * quantity;
        }
    }

    public bool validated { get; set; }
    public bool rejected { get; set; }
}
```

I am attempting to "split" an order using the following code based on a JSON config file entry that specifies which fields to split the order on (parameter 2):

```
   private List<OrderRequest> SplitOrder(OrderRequest originalOrder, string[] orderSplitLineItemFields = null)
    {
        var retval = new List<OrderRequest>();
        if (null == orderSplitLineItemFields || originalOrder.items.Count < 2) //Can't return more than one order if we don't have fields to split by, and we don't have at least 2 line items.
        {
            retval.Add(originalOrder);
        }
        else
        {
            var bareOrderHeader = (OrderRequest)originalOrder.DeepClone();
            bareOrderHeader.items.Clear();
            var firstLineItem = originalOrder.items[0];
            var validOrderSplitLineItemFields = new List<string>();
            var dynamicQueryBase =  new List<string>();
            int validFieldCount = 0;
            foreach (var field in orderSplitLineItemFields)
            {
                if (firstLineItem.HasProperty(field))
                {
                    validOrderSplitLineItemFields.Add(field);
                    dynamicQueryBase.Add(field + " = @" + validFieldCount++);
                }
                else if (null != firstLineItem.other[field])
                {
                    validOrderSplitLineItemFields.Add("other[\"" + field + "\"]");
                    dynamicQueryBase.Add("other[\"" + field + "\"]" + " = @" + validFieldCount++);
                }
            }
            if(validOrderSplitLineItemFields.Count<1) //Can't return more than one order if we don't have valid fields to split by.
            {
                retval.Add(originalOrder);
            }
            else //We have valid fields to split the order, so we might be able to return more than one order.
            {

                string distinctFields = String.Join(",", validOrderSplitLineItemFields);
                var distinctFieldValues = originalOrder.items.AsQueryable().Select(distinctFields).Distinct();
                var dynamicWhere = string.Join(" and ", dynamicQueryBase);
                var originalLineItems = originalOrder.items.AsQueryable();
                foreach (var distinctResult in distinctFieldValues)
                {
                    var newOrderSplit = (OrderRequest)bareOrderHeader.DeepClone();

                    var results = originalLineItems.Where(dynamicWhere, distinctResult);
                    foreach (var lineitem in results)
                    {
                        newOrderSplit.items.Add(lineitem);
                    }

                    retval.Add(newOrderSplit);
                }
            }
        }
        return retval;
    }
```

The field that I am attempting to split on is called "requested_delivery_date" which is being properly passed in to the SplitOrder function. Because this is not an actual property of OrderRequestItem, the split code checks (and in fact succeeds) in looking at/finding a dictionary entry in the "other" property and appropriately adds the field to the list of dynamic fields upon which to query--(I do it this way because the specifically defined properties are "required" and I won't be able to predict what additional fields we may be sent on future orders with other buyers).

I have a sample order file that contains 4 line items. The lines 1, 2, 3 all have a defined other["requested_delivery_date"] = 2018-09-29, and line 4 has a other["requested_delivery_date"] = 2018-09-30.

Based on the code, I would expect to return two orders, one with line items 1-3, and another with only line 4. However, what I am *actually* getting back is two orders, one with only line item #1, and another with only line item #4. It seems as though the line

```
var results = originalLineItems.Where(dynamicWhere, distinctResult);
```

only ever returns a single result when I query against the dictionary that is a member of OrderRequestItem.

I have been beating my head against the wall here for the better part of the day and I don't understand why I only get a single result when the debugger is showing me that the original list of items I am querying have more matches. I'm starting to think it is a bug in the current version of System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.

Any help/suggestions appreciated! Keep in mind that I need to use dynamic linq since I will be dealing with new or changed additional fields on the line items all the time--so going back to "regular linq" isn't an option here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed this

```
dynamicQueryBase.Add("other[\"" + field + "\"]" + " = @" + validFieldCount++);
```

to this

```
dynamicQueryBase.Add("other[\"" + field + "\"].ToString()" + " = @" + validFieldCount++);
```

makes it work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test right now, maybe the default return for "where" is only a single item.
Try

```
var results = originalLineItems.Where(dynamicWhere, distinctResult).ToList();
```

And check if it's working fine.

Comment: Already tried .ToList(), I got the same result so I removed it. AND, if I query against a member property of OrderRequestItem (as opposed to the "other" Dictionary) I get the results I would expect.